# Rails says where query is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a web application using Rails 3.2.6 and when I try to do this query it compains about the comma after the first half of the query.

```
Checkin.where ("user_id = ? AND event_id = ?", current_user.id, params[:event_id])
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: which comma do you mean  I see no comma in the query

Comment: It's helpful to post the actual error message. I assume it's something like `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `where` and opening `(`.

```
Checkin.where("user_id = ? AND event_id = ?", current_user.id, params[:event_id])
```

Comment: Thanks, didn´t know that the whitespace counted.